# Androidでスマホ､タブレット､縦､横で異なるLayoutを実現する｡

Tags: android, android-volley, http, android-layout, android-fragments

例えばスマホ(縦)､(横)､タブレット(縦)､(横)の4つのレイアウトフォルダを作ることで実装するとします｡ そしてそれぞれのレイアウトは

- スマホ(縦)
  `Fragment A`,`Fragment B`
- スマホ(横)
  `Fragment A`
- タブレット(縦)
  `Fragment A`,`Fragment C`
- タブレット(横)
  `Fragment A`,`Fragment D`,`Fragment E`

となっています｡  
この内､`Fragment A`以外のフラグメントは`View`の表示内容にHttp通信で得られるデータを用います｡
その､Http通信には`Volley`ライブラリを用います｡  `Volley`ライブラリはリクエスト時に`ApplicationContext`が必要です｡

この場合はどこでHttpリクエストをしたらよいのでしょうか｡
例えば､親の`Activity`の`onCreate()`内でリクエストした場合､`Fragment`側にデータを送ることはできると思うのですが､すでに`Fragment`側の`onCreateView()`が終わっているはずなので`View`をセットすることがでないと考えられます｡
また､`Fragment`でリクエストするとしましたら､`Fragment`側の`onCreateView()`では、まだ`Activity`の`onCreated()`が終わっていないため､`ApplicationContext`を取得できないと考えられます｡

こういった場合の実装方法を教えてください。よろしくお願い致します

Comment: 回答ありがとうございました｡  書き忘れていたのですが､これらの各フラグメントで使用するデータは同じなので､今回は､Activityでデータを取得することにしました｡

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Fragment`から、`Activity`の`onCreated()`が実行された後に行いたい処理がある場合は、[`onActivityCreated()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onActivityCreated(android.os.Bundle))のコールバックが利用できます。

この場合、`onCreateView()`で表示するビューは空か、もしくは読み込み中を表すインディケーターにして、後から更新することになるので、`Activity`の`onCreate()`で通信を行って、通信結果に応じて`Fragment`の表示を更新する作りにしてもあまり変わりませんが…。

Answer (score 1):

やりたい事が「通信して表示」なので、`Loader`を使って次のように実装するのはどうでしょうか？

1. 各`Fragment`の`onActivityCreated()`で、`LoaderManager`を取得し、`initLoader()`で初期化
2. `initLoader()`の引数で指定する`LoaderCallbacks`の`onCreateLoader`で、「リクエストを`Volley`で投げて、データを取得する`Loader`」を生成
3. 生成した`Loader`内で`Volley`を使ってリクエストを投げる。`Loader`のコンストラクタには`Context`があるので、`ApplicationContext`は取得できる
4. リクエストの結果を`deliverResult()`で伝える。
5. `LoaderCallbacks`の`onLoadFinished()`が呼ばれるので、`View`にそのデータをセットする